# Как составить и использовать функцию, которая будет возвращать два значения

Tags: c++

Составить функцию поиска суммы и произведения трех целых чисел. Найти с ее помощью сумму и произведение шести данных чисел.

Comment: можете использовать std::pair. Но думается мне, что в задании просят создать 2 функции

Comment: Дело в том, что там подразумевается использование только одной функции...

Comment: А мне кажется, что возвратить структуру будет удобнее. `struct S {double sum; double prod;};`

Comment: По [принципу единственной отвественности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) лучше всё же сделать 2 разные функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как вариант

```
void sum_and_mult(int a, int b, int c, int &sum, int &mult) {
  sum = 0;
  mult = 1;
  sum = a + b + c;
  mult = a * b*c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
struct sum_prod {
    int sum;
    int prod;
};

// function can returns structures
struct sum_prod
sum_and_prod (int a, int b, int c) 
{
    struct sum_prod result;
    result.sum = a + b + c;
    result.prod = a * b * c;

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Судя по вопросу (который на мой взгляд составлен криво), суть задания была в функций с переменным числом параметров.

```
#define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>


template<typename... T2>
int s_and_c(auto f, const T2&... args) {
    auto il = std::initializer_list<int>{args...};
    std::vector<int> v(il);

    return f(v);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    UNUSED(argc);
    UNUSED(argv);

    auto f_sum{[](std::vector<int>& v){return std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0, [](int a, int b){return a + b;});}};
    auto f_c{[](std::vector<int>& v){return std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 1, [](int a, int b){return a * b;});}};

    auto s1 = s_and_c(f_sum, 1);
    std::cout << "res : " << s1 << std::endl;
    auto s1_c = s_and_c(f_c, 1);
    std::cout << "res : " << s1_c << std::endl;

    auto s2 = s_and_c(f_sum, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    std::cout << "res : " << s2 << std::endl;
    auto s2_c = s_and_c(f_c, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    std::cout << "res : " << s2_c << std::endl;

    auto s3 = s_and_c(f_sum, 1, 2, 3);
    std::cout << "res : " << s3 << std::endl;
    auto s3_c = s_and_c(f_c, 1, 2, 3);
    std::cout << "res : " << s3_c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не могли бы Вы пояснить, из чего Вы вывели предположение о переменном числе аргументов?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Добрый день Юрий, да могу. Когда мы пишем любой код, надо думать об универсальности функции а не о костылях как в ответе AR Hovsepyan. Зачем Нам держать функцию которая складывает 3 числа, потом 4 числа нам понадобится и т.д. Надо написать 1 универсальную функцию, и она будет работать. 2 Я поправил свой ответ - теперь от отвечает принципу единой ответственности.

Comment: Это все, конечно, верно. За исключением одного нюанса: это учебное задание, а в них обычно требуется сделать именно то, что сказал преподаватель.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Данный ответ полностью удовлетворяет ТЗ преподователя, и даже больше)

Comment: не соглашусь. В задании (как оно описано ТС) сказано абсолютно однозначно: Функция ТРЕХ аргументов. И с ее помощью найти сумму и произведение 6 чисел.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Мы просто чуть-чуть расширили функционал ) да  и универсальный ответ намного лучше) Все-же программирование это решение задачи, а не писание костылей и захардкоживание решения конкретных кейсов.

Comment: Ни Вы ни я не знаем, какие цели преследовал преподаватель, давая эту задачу. Так же ,как не знаем, знаком ли уже ТС с функциями с переменным числом аргументов и  с шаблонами. Я бы согласился с Вашей позицией, если бы речь шла о каком-то рабочем проекте, да и то - при условии, что есть вероятность появления разного числа аргументов. А для учебного задания - нет, не согласен. В учебном задании, все же, нужно делать то, что сказал преподаватель. Хотя бы потому, что получив не то решение, которое ему требовалось, преподаватель может снизить оценку, даже если решение будет верно работать

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов  - написание кода это искусство и творческий процесс, грош цена тому преподу, который не оценит старание ученика сделать код лучше, и универсальнее.

Comment: и снова не соглашусь. Всему свое время. Для начала нужно заложить крепкую базу, а уж потом начинать "делать код лучше и универсальнее" Тем более что утверждение, что универсальное всегда лучше - весьма спорное. Но как бы то ни было, наша дискуссия, на мой взгляд, переросла рамки допустимого для комментариев. Предлагаю или прекратить ее, или, хотя бы, перенести в чат.